# Direct Mapping of 8GByte memory with 64-bit addressable word size

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, memory-address, cpu-cache

**The question**: A computer has 8 GByte of memory with 64-bit addressable word sizes. Each block of memory stores 16 words. The computer has a direct-mapping cache of 128 blocks

1. Calculate the tag bits, Line number bits, and offset bit.

**To solve the question, here is what I did.**
8GB = 1GW (64 bit word = 8 bytes/word), which requires `30 bits (log 2 1G = 30)`. The
memory address is divided into line number and word number. With 16 words per line,
we need 4 bits for the block offset.
Next, since block stores 16 words, there must be 16 lines in cache to store 128 blocks so `line number bits 4` (log 2 16 = 4) and then or tag bits 30 - 4 - 4 = 22 bits for tag bits.

Please tell me if this is correct or not? If not, provide solution.

On an unrelated note, to get Tag bits is this formula valid, `log 2 (main memory size / cache size)`.

Comment: I think you've made a reduction: the line number/index must accommodate 128 blocks so the size of the index must be log2(128), no?  In other words, the size of this direct mapped cache is 128 block entries x 16 words per block x 8 bytes per word, i.e. 16kB.

Comment: oh so `line number` is basically an index to block number? I thought the tag bits tell the block number and line number bits tell which line number, because we will have fewer lines for 128 blocks that's why only 4 bits for line number

Comment: No, tag bits are for verification of match only.  They are used after the selection of the line/position holding the potential data block.